# Xcode Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle when not using storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to create a UIButton only with codes.
I got this message with SIGABORT, but I'm not using the main storyboard. I'm not sure if there is still an element of the main storyboard.

How should I fix this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 340, y: 10, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height / 4))
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.setTitle("filter", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pushButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

@objc func pushButton(sender: UIButton){
    print("button pushed")
}
```

Comment: Did you remove the reference to your main storyboard from the "Main Interface" field of your target's general settings in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup rootViewController on SceneDelegate if you have XCode 11+ and you can do it like this:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
    self.window?.rootViewController = YourViewController() //UINavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController()) this if you want your controller to be inside navigation.
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}

func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
    // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
    // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
    // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
}

func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
    // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
}

func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
    // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
}

func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
    // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
}

func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
    // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
    // to restore the scene back to its current state.
}
```

}

Also you need to delete 'Main Interface' field from targets general settings check the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What @Adriatik Gashi said is right, only one more thing to do after that:

In the `plist` file go to:

Open `Application Scene Manifest`

1. Open `Scene Configuration`
2. Open `Application Session Role
3. Open `item 0`
4. Delete `StoryBoard name`

[image]